# Batch Renaming of Files in a Directory Following a Specific Rule

Tags: python, file-io, rename

Is there an easy way to rename files already contained in a directory in this specific way using Python?

I have a directory full of images named like

```
1 - imgA.jpg
2 - imgB.jpg
3 - imgC.jpg
```

I would like to rename them as

```
3 - imgA.jpg
2 - imgB.jpg
1 - imgC.jpg
```

Comment: what is your *Specific Rule* (if there would be 20 files)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> filenames = ['1 - imgA.jpg', '2 - imgB.jpg', '3 - imgC.jpg']
>>> filenames_split = [tuple(map(str.strip, f.split('-'))) for f in filenames]
>>> filenames_split
[('1', 'imgA.jpg'), ('2', 'imgB.jpg'), ('3', 'imgC.jpg')]
>>> 
>>> n = len(filenames_split)
>>> 
>>> filenames_split_new = [(str(n-int(number)+1), f) for number, f in filenames_split]
>>> filenames_split_new
[('3', 'imgA.jpg'), ('2', 'imgB.jpg'), ('1', 'imgC.jpg')]
>>> new_filenames = [' - '.join((number, f)) for number, f in filenames_split_new]
>>> new_filenames
['3 - imgA.jpg', '2 - imgB.jpg', '1 - imgC.jpg']
```

But you'll have to first open and then re-save the files, right? Perhaps try this:

```
from PIL import Image

together = zip(filenames, new_filenames)

for f, new_f in together:
    with Image.open(f) as opened_f:
        opened_f.save(new_f)
```

Or you could use `os.rename`, which I didn't know existed:

```
together = zip(filenames, new_filenames)

for f, new_f in together:
    os.rename(f, new_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest way is to write a small routine in Excel (Office) VBA like this:

Use **`Dir > CurrDirectory.Txt`** from Command.Com (old DOS trick:  > symbol redirects output to named file!

Load the CurrDirectory.Txt into an Excel sheet.
Use any code necessary to create new file names.

Step through each file using:

OldName = The old name loaded
NewName = The newly created name

```
Name OldName As NewName
```

Loop through all needed

- Be sure to inlude Path names to get files in right location

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use the modules "re" and "os" to achieve it:

```
import re, os

directory_name = "C:\\oneFolder\\"
rough_list = os.listdir(directory_name)
filtered_list = []

# filter the result to just files complying the pattern
for name in rough_list:
    match = re.match("(\d+)( - img[A-Z]+.jpg)", name)
    if match :
        filtered_list.append([int(match.group(1)), match.group(0), match.group(2)])

# max num of digits
mx = len(str(max(filtered_list)[0]))

# create a list reversed indices
num = range(len(filtered_list), 0, -1)

# rename the files accordingly
for i,name in enumerate(sorted(filtered_list)):
    os.rename(directory_name + name[1], directory_name + str(num[i]).zfill(mx) + name[2])
```